# In Scala.JS is there a call to get the platform I'm running on?

Tags: scala.js

I have some Scala code for a library which I compile for both the JVM and ScalaJS.

Right now I have a "pure" project, without special code in the js and jvm proojects, and I'd like to keep it that way due to intellij integration and some other factors.

However, I do have a small bit of code (1-2 lines) that needs to change based on whether I'm in the JVM or JS.  I'd like an easy way to accomplish this that doesn't require me changing my whole project structure.

Basically I'd like a call "isJS" that returns true if I'm on JavaScript and false otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing standard, as it would require to extend the API available on the JVM, which Scala.js cannot do.

You can build it yourself easily with a tiny `object Platform` with two different implementations in the `js/` and `jvm/` subprojects. For example for JS it would be:

```
object Platform {
  final val isJS = true
  final val isJVM = false
}
```

Of course that requires to be non-pure. You could also abstract that in a tiny library offering only that feature. That is what the `platform` project of [catalysts](https://github.com/InTheNow/catalysts) does, for example.

If you want to keep completely pure and no dependency, you have to resort to a hack:

```
val isJS = 1.0.toString == "1"
```

This works because, on the JVM, `1.0.toString` returns `"1.0"`, but on JS it returns `"1"`.

Comment: Thanks, the toString hack is exactly what I wanted.  If I end up needing more I'll go and change my project structure, but this will work perfectly for the small thing I need now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
val isJS = System.getProperty("java.vm.name") == "Scala.js"
```

Comment: Although this is an easy and reliable way to do it, bear in mind that it costs you a lot in code size, since it brings a non-trivial part of the `java.util` package into your .js file. (if you already use `java.util.Map`s elsewhere, it's not a big deal, but otherwise it can make a big difference)